# Polygon inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry

[image: Inscribed polygon]

There is a picture of an inscribed n-side polygon in a circle above. I have a task as follow:

> If an n-sided regular polygon is inscribed in a circle of radius r, find a relationship between θ and n. Solve this for n. Keep in mind there are 2π radians in a circle. (Use radians, not degrees.)

Everything what comes to my mind is θ = 2π/n, but I'm pretty sure, that is not correct answer. Could you help me to deal with it please?

Comment: How many copies of this angle $\theta$ will make up the entire $2\pi$ of the circle?

Comment: Is this a hint? If not, then n copies of . n is from task definition.

Comment: Yes, a hint. That means $n\cdot \theta = 2\pi$. Keep in mind that you are being asked to solve for $n$, so write as $n =$___

Answer (score 1):

Given that the inscribed polygon is regular, we can say that the angle subtended between any 2 line segments (originating from adjacent corners) at the center of the circle will be equal and since there will be $n$ unique angles totaling up to $2π$, each of them will be equal to $\frac{2π}{n}$.

Your answer is correct and  $θ=\frac{2π}{n}$.

Comment: Yeah, θ = 2π/n is correct, but I think that is quite not what the task wants from me. Too simple, isn't it?

Comment: @morris From reading it, it seems this is exactly what they are asking (aside from wanting you to solve for $n$).